# Lima Bean Experiment

Tags: word-request

A student of mine is writing about her experience when she opened a Baggie of lima beans that had begun to rot. The smell was gross, like rotten garbage. A few sentences she wrote are "When we opened our Baggies. Our senses exploded! ¨Hear¨ are some of the _______________ my senses experienced!" What word could she use in the blank?

Comment: Hi Carol, welcome to ELL! There's plenty of people here ready and willing to help people with learning English. However, we generally hope that people will have made some effort to figure out or find an answer or their own, and it's very helpful if you can give some indication of that in the question. If you've tried a translation dictionary, say why you aren't happy with what it gave you. If you've tried a thesaurus, tell us what you found and why you don't like it.

Answer (score 2):

There are a lot of mistakes here. The first two sentences should be one sentence:

> When we opened our baggies, our senses exploded!

Though this is syntactically ok, semantically I am not sure. Wasn’t it only one baggie that was the problem? Therefore, “When I opened my baggie...” would be better.

“Our senses exploded” may be understood but it is a weird thing to say. “Our senses were assaulted” or “Our noses were assaulted” if it was just the smell that was noticeable, might make more sense.

I think “baggie” should be lowercase even though “Baggie” might be a brand name (common enough that lowercasing it is fine, like with “kleenex”).

“Here”, not “Hear”. “Here are some of the smells our noses were hit with” perhaps.

Answer (score 1):

a possible word is: sensations

Answer (score 1):

If you want to be specific, ***sensations***.

If you're fine being prosaic, ***things***.

It's a bit tenuous, but more specific than *things* and less repetitious (in terms of the senses), you could have ***impressions***.